# Always Lost connection to device. when using imagePicker in Android Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, imagepicker

Hay... I try to understand using ImagePicker flutter plugin, but somehow I can open my camera using ImagePicker until the device keeps losing connection. (I'm using a real device, not an emulator).

this is my image picker code looks like :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class FormTree extends StatefulWidget {
  const FormTree({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FormTreeState createState() => _FormTreeState();
}

class _FormTreeState extends State<FormTree> {

  File? image;

  Future pickImage() async {
    image = File(await ImagePicker()
            .pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera)
            .then((pickedFile) => pickedFile!.path));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
     appBar: //AppBarCode,
     body: Container(
        ElevatedButton.icon(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.camera_alt_rounded),
          onPressed: () => pickImage(), //in this I call imagePicker function
          label: const Text("Photo"),
          style: elevatedFormButton,
        ),
     ),
   )
  }
}
```

when I click that `ElevatedButton` the camera will appear but not long enough the device will lose connection.

```
I/Timeline(22893): Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:128614756
W/ActivityThread(22893): SCHED: com.example.project/.MainActivity [84, r=280ms, a=52ms, w=883937ms]
Lost connection to device.
```

how do I suppose to be using ImagePicker? or how do I keep the device connection when the picture intake?

Comment: There might be damage in your USB cable. Try it with connecting it with tcpip connection

Comment: Whenever app goes in the background, Android studio will lose connection with device.

Comment: @swamper, thanks, it's work... but I don't see any damage in my USB cable tho... that it will make sense if the projectApp can't go in the background like karan-mehta says. so what is the difference between using TCP IP and USB Cable in running flutter projectApp?

Comment: @DVCone There is not much difference while you try to run a app with USB the data transfer happens with cable but it TCP IP method the PC and external device should connect to same wifi network in order to start data transfer. As you said you're working with USB the problem may be with cable else it will be with the port but in TCP IP connection this problems can be solved.

Comment: @swamper ok never mind. at first, I used port 5555 in TCPIP it's work but somehow now it's doesn't work anymore. the issue is the same when I use a USB Cable... maybe there is an alternative port or something I miss?

Comment: @DVCone That's strange changing the ports might not solve this! Something is going on.